# Join taking far too long!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.5

I am joining points to polygons in ArcGIS (10.5), but this is taking a ridiculous amount of time (roughly a week!). The points are climatic data covering the UK - approx 450,000 points. The polygon is a fishnet covering the UK, each cell is 500m^2 (approx 3.8m cells). I don't know how to find the important information that may help to understand why its taking so long, e.g. data formats, volumes etc..

Comment: That's a tiny table. There's no reason a table under 100m rows should process in over 24 hours. 64-bit geoprocesing (which *isn't* a "patch") won't do it any faster until you fix whatever fundamental problem you have in the data. Cancel the job, and provide enough information about what you are attempting (data formats,  volumes, indexes, and exact command) so we can help you, and the execution should complete within two minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. The join is a point to polygon join. Points are climatic data covering the UK - approx 450,000 points. The polygon is a fishnet covering the UK, each cell is 500m^2 (approx 3.8m cells). I don't know how to find the data formats, volumes etc...

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to add information. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to scour the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be taking that long to join tables. I suspect there is something going on with your hardware and/or software configuration.

If you are doing a table join, I would recommend exporting your features to a personal geodatabase and trying the join in Microsoft Access to test if it is a software issue. Access should be faster either way, Arcmap is notoriously slow with joins.

Personal gdb:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/personal-geodatabases.htm

MS Access joins:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx